# Error with requests.model.Response.json(): JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

When trying to request an API, I'm able to connect successfully with this authentication and GET call:

```
#Wells API request:
url = 'https://prd-api-quorumfield.azurewebsites.net/wells'

headers = {
    'AuthID' : authenticate_response.json()['AuthID']
    }

wells_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

When I test the response, I show that I connected successfully:

```
wells_response

<Response [200]>
```

However, when I try to call the .json() method, I receive the following error:

```
wells_response.json()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-213-c84bd04c5949> in <module>
----> 1 wells_response.json()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    896                     # used.
    897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    899 
    900     @property

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Other methods such as .headers and .content seem to work correctly; just not the .json().

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The response is not a JSON response. Try printing the response, e.g. `print(wells_response.text)` to see what you are getting back from the server. Also take a look at the Content-type in the response headers: `print(wells_response.headers['Content-Type'])`

Comment: Thanks! 
```print(wells_response.headers['Content-Type'])``` returned text/html, and ```print(wells_response.text)``` returned: 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>GetWells Snapshot of 3/9/2021 1:26:17 AM</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
etc. 

Does the fact that it starts with "<" indicate it's not a json file?

Comment: So the response is HTML. This is not JSON. If this is not what you expect then you will need to look at the request which might not match the API. Possibly you need to specify that you want a JSON response.

Comment: Try `requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={'format': 'json'})` which will request a JSON response from that server.

Comment: Genius. This worked! Thanks so much for the recommendation!